# Installing RTL8811 Wifi Adapter Drivers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I'm having trouble installing the drivers for my wifi adapter, which acording to this page (https://www.amitosai.com/?pagina=producto&id=47) uses the Realtek RTL8811 chipset.

I follow this instructions:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/whitebatman2/rtl8821CU.git
DRV_NAME=rtl8821CU
DRV_VERSION=5.2.5.3
sudo mkdir /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
cd $DRV_NAME
git archive master | sudo tar -x -C /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
sudo dkms add -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
sudo dkms build -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
sudo dkms install -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
```

But it didn't work.

This is the info when i run lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 Hub
```

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Later that day, my Ubuntu system stops forever, so I reinstalled it and now I'm using a wired connection.

Comment: could you solved it? I'm trying to install the driver of the same adapter. In your procedure there are some errors, the driver we need is RTL8811 not RTL8821, that's the main reason it doesn't work for you....

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
cd rtl8821CU
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
sudo modprobe 8821cu
```

Regards

Comment: it returns: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8821cu': Exec format error

Comment: Wonderful!, it worked for my EDUP 11AC 600M USB Wireless Adapter ( Model EP-AC1631). Thanks! a lot!

Comment: within repo readme there are extra steps